# Why does $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lfloor y-x\rfloor<y-M, \mbox{ for all $y>M$ } \}=(M,\infty)$?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $M$ be a fixed real number. During our research, we have obtained the following identities.
$$
\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lfloor y-x\rfloor<y-M, \mbox{ for all $y>M$ } \}=(M,\infty),
$$
$$
\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lfloor y-x\rfloor\leq y-M, \mbox{ for all $y\geq M$ }\}=[M,\infty).
$$
It may be interesting to check them directly. Do you have a direct solution to prove it?

**Observation.** Let $X$ be the left side set of the first identity and $x\in X$. Putting
$y=\lfloor M+1\rfloor$ we conclude that $x>M-1$. Also, if $x>M+1$, then $\lfloor y-x\rfloor\leq \lfloor y-M-1\rfloor<y-M$ and so
$x\in X$. Thus $(M+1,\infty)\subseteq X\subseteq (M-1,\infty)$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you have a direct solution to prove it?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): what did you try?

Comment: As mentioned, this result was obtained by a method that cannot be described here, and we are looking for a preliminary solution for it. Of course, the stated observation gives a clue to approach the answer.

Comment: Why cannot your method be described here? And how does the observation give any clue?

Comment: In fact, (M,+∞) and [M,+∞)  are additive sub-semigroups of real numbers, if $M\geq 0$. Recently, we have introduced a concept called the centralization of upper periodic real sets, which includes real semigroups, and we have proved a theorem, an example of which is the result mentioned. And with the appropriate choices for y
, it may be possible to reach a direct solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both equalities, the inclusion $\supseteq$ results from $\lfloor y-x\rfloor\le y-x.$ Let us prove $\subseteq$ by contradiction.

Choose some integer $n>M-x,$ and let $y:=n+x>M.$

- Assume first $x\le M.$ Then, $\lfloor y-x\rfloor=n\ge n+x-M=y-M,$ which proves that $x$ doesn't belong to the set at the left of the 1st equality.
- Assume now $x<M.$ Similarly, $\lfloor y-x\rfloor=n>n+x-M=y-M,$ which proves that $x$ doesn't belong to the set at the left of the 2nd equality.

This proof by contradiction can be reformulated as a direct proof, with the same choice for $n$ and $y:$

- Assume first that $x$ belongs to the set at the left of the 1st equality. Then, $n=\lfloor y-x\rfloor<y-M=n+x-M,$ hence $x>M.$
- Similarly, assume now that $x$ belongs to the set at the left of the 2nd equality. Then, $n=\lfloor y-x\rfloor\le y-M=n+x-M,$ hence $x\ge M.$

Comment: Thanks. In your opinion, can we think of a direct solution for $\subseteq$ (without proof by contradiction)?

Comment: Thanks again.  Regarding your second proof, if $x$ belongs to the set at the left of the 1st equality, then how do you infer that $y:=n+x$ is greater than $M$ where $n=\lfloor y-x\rfloor$?

Comment: In both proofs, I first chose an integer $n>M-x$ and let $y$ be $n+x,$ to get both $y>M$ and$\lfloor y-x\rfloor=\lfloor n\rfloor=n.$ I didn't derive the former from the latter.